# Abstract image puzzle with a rotating arrow and a circle

Tags: pattern, geometry

[image]

**What is the next image?**

I already found the rule for the circle. Which simply goes around clockwise in the corners. So, the correct choice is either C or D. But, I do not find such a rule for the arrow.

Attribution: [This site](https://europa.eu/epso/application/passport/index.cfm?action=int_test&intact=dsp_ar_tests)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I  believe the pattern for the arrow is

> alternating between clockwise and anti-clockwise and increasing distance by one eighth of the square each time. i.e. clockwise 1, anti-clockwise 2, clockwise 3 etc.

Which would make the answer

> C

Answer (score 6):

I choose

> C

Because

> The circle rotates around the corners clockwise, so it can be either C or D (as you also found). The line seems to be following a pattern as well: west, northwest, southwest, north, south, *northeast*, southeast, east.

Comment: This answer is good as well. I liked the mathematical pattern discovered by Andrew, so I accepted his response.

Answer (score 1):

I choose

> **C**

The arrow goes up half, down one, up one & a half, down two. Therefore the next move would be up two & a half. (Up = Clockwise, down = anti-clockwise, one = a whole side from corner to corner)

The circle moves one space clockwise.

Answer (score 0):

> "C"
> So the circle goes around the corners of the square clockwise... The arrows seem to continue a path... and since you never have END TO END nor TIP TO TIP...   so between C and D answers, has to be C

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE! Remember to check first if the answer you are going to post has already been added, especially if there is one that has already been accepted. In general answers should only be posted if they really add something. If you would like more guidance on how this site works (and get your first badge) check out the tour: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour    and the help center: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help